# docker run results in starting container process caused "exec: \"./boot.sh\": permission denied

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm following *Flask Web Development [2nd ed.]* by Miguel Grinberg. In Part III Chapter 17 it instructs how to deploy a project to Docker. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on VMware.

1. I successfully build a container image by running `docker build -t flasky:latest .`.
2. Running `docker images` I verify that the image was succesfully created.
3. I fail at running the container using:

```
docker run --name flasky -d -p 8000:5000 \
-e SECRET_KEY=<secret_key> \
-e MAIL_USERNAME=<my_email> \
-e MAIL_PASSWORD=<my_password> flasky:latest
```

As a result I get this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"./boot.sh\": permission denied": unknown.

I tried modifying permissions with `chmod`, but to no avail. Then again, maybe I did it wrong.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ENV FLASK_APP flasky.py
ENV FLASK_CONFIG docker

RUN adduser -D flasky
USER flasky

WORKDIR /home/flasky

COPY requirements requirements
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements/docker.txt

COPY app app
COPY migrations migrations
COPY flasky.py config.py boot.sh ./

# runtime configuration
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

boot.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
source venv/bin/activate
flask deploy
exec gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - flasky:app
```

I tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54336677/12853922) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57802199/12853922). The problem persists. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried to set `chown` on your entry script to your user. And also set `chmod 4755` on it

Comment: I haven't tried `chown`, but I'll keep note of it for the future. Thanks! I already resolved the issue by using one of the solutions given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `chmod a+x boot.sh` or `chmod o+x boot.sh`

You are running as user `flasky` inside the container `USER flasky` and as a result executing the `boot.sh` script as that user. The problem here is that `flasky` do not have permission to execute the script.

Let's say you are running as user `app_user` under group `app_group` in your host machine and tried to give the script execution right like `chmod +x boot.sh`. It will only allow users `app_user` to execute the script.

If you execute the command `chmod g+x boot.sh`, it will allow any user that belongs to the group `app_group` to be able to execute it.

Since we never specify any id for `app_user` in host machine nor `flasky` user in the container, you will have to run the command `chmod a+x boot.sh` or `chmod o+x boot.sh` which give other users the permission to execute `boot.sh`.

The reason for all this trouble is because in Linux, the user id in a container is mapped directly to the user id in the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod +x boot.sh` should solve your problem. I could reproduce the issue when `chmod +x` was not done-

```
root@qa9phx:~/amitp/p3# docker run -it 62591cab9f07 bash
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"./boot.sh\": permission denied": unknown.
```

Here's the sample Dockerfile that I used-

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

COPY boot.sh ./
# runtime configuration
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

Here's the sample boot.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello world"
```

Run the following command before building the docker

```
chmod +x boot.sh
```

Then docker build-

```
docker build -t flasky:latest .
```

Docker images listing-

```
root@qa9phx:~/amitp/p3# docker images
REPOSITORY                             TAG                                      IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
flasky                                 latest                                   6d10284c0d9e        8 minutes ago       94.6MB
```

Docker run command-

```
root@qa9phx:~/amitp/p3# docker run -it 6d10284c0d9e bash
hello world
```

Comment: The issue persisted after `chmod +x boot.sh`, but it was a close call. Changing permissions with `chmod a+x boot.sh` as suggested by Nguyen Lam Phuc worked.